# Is there a command line tool to get the list of content of current kernel used in my Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

by this command

```
uname -r
```

I got the version of current kernel used in my Ubuntu.

```
4.19.0-041900-generic
```

I would like to know more detail, such as the type of the version of file system, VFS, device drivers, etc contained in the kernel.

Is there a command line tool for that? or I have to check this out on launchpad.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such universal command. Linux kernel contains very many device drivers.

Generally in-tree device drivers don't have a separate "version". Their version is the kernel version.

You can find all the details about the driver in kernel sources.