# what version of AMDGPU -

Tags: apt, package-management, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

[Which version of Amdgpu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173984/which-version-of-amdgpu)

[Is there a command line tool to get the list of content of current kernel used in my Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171903/is-there-a-command-line-tool-to-get-the-list-of-content-of-current-kernel-used-i)

neither of these have answered the actual question...I dont mean to be rude, but i was in need of the same information....this is what i found

def@xeon:~$ apt list --installed | grep -i amdgpu-pro

amdgpu-pro/unknown,now 18.50-725072 amd64 [installed]
amdgpu-pro-core/unknown,now 18.50-725072 all [installed,automatic]
amdgpu-pro-lib32/unknown,now 18.50-725072 amd64 [installed]
amdgpu-pro-pin/unknown,now 18.50-725072 all [installed]
trimmed

I believe that would indicate that I have amdgpu version 18.50-725072

tested on another machine with 19.20:

def@mineshaft:~$ apt list --installed | grep -i amdgpu-pro

amdgpu-pro-core/now 19.20-812932 all [installed,local]
amdgpu-pro-pin/now 19.20-812932 all [installed,local]
clinfo-amdgpu-pro/now 19.20-812932 amd64 [installed,local]
trimmed

One correct answer to how to find your amdgpu version is:
    apt list --installed | grep -i amdgpu-pro

def

Answer (score 1):

apt list --installed | grep -i amdgpu-pro